# Smooth Scrolling on anchor links

Tags: jquery

I try to create a smooth scrolling in a website with jQuery. This the code I use at the moment:

```
(function(jQuery) {    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var anchor = jQuery(this);
                    console.log(anchor.attr('href'));

                    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                       scrollTop: (jQuery(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 95)
                    }, 1500,'linear');
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

However, the `anchor` is the whole link (like `www.mydomain.com/#myanchor`) and obviously, it doesn't work. I was thinking to get the anchor id with something like this:

```
anchor = anchor.substring(anchor.indexOf("#")+1);
```

However, I may have conflicts and console errors with links that are not on the same page. Is this sufficient or I should do it with another way?

P.S. Not every `a` in my `nav` has an anchor link. Some have full links to other pages.

Comment: `jQuery('nav a[href^="#"]')` will yield only links that start with `#`, which I think should be the only links for which you want to bind this listener.

Comment: It's really appreciated to leave a comment with the reason when you down-vote a question. Otherwise, the OP will not understand why you did it and he will just do it again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you only want to do this with anchors on the same page, and so the links in question should start with `#`. **Edit:** But you've said they may start with the page URL anyway.

> Not every a in my nav has an anchor link.

So first we have to filter those out, which is easy:

```
var href = anchor.attr("href");
if (href.charAt(0) === "#" || href.startsWith(location + "#")) {
    // Yes, we want to scroll it
}
```

*(Note that `String#startsWith` may need a shim for non-cutting-edge browsers, but the shim is trivial.)*

or better yet, as [David Hedlund said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393045/smooth-scrolling-on-anchor-links/34393163#comment56527426_34393045), just only select them in the first place:

```
var loc = location.toString().split("#")[0];
jQuery('nav a[href^="#"], nav a[href^="' + loc + '#"]').bind(...
```

...which looks for `a href="#blah"` and also `a href="http://my.website.com/#blah` assuming the current URL is `http://my.website.com/`.

> I was thinking to get the anchor id with something like this...
>
> ```
> anchor = anchor.substring(anchor.indexOf("#")+1);
> ```

That would work just fine now that we're filtering out the irrelevant links. But note that in your code, `anchor` is a jQuery object, but you're treating it like a string. Instead:

```
var href = anchor.attr("href");
href = href.substring(href.indexOf("#")+1);
```

...and then we can use `href` as an `id` selector:

```
var targetElement = $(href);
```

Since the `#` is there, it turns into an `id` selector, and we can look it up using the `href` directly (e.g., `#foo` is the href, and also an `id` selector for the target element).

---

Side note: `bind` is the old way (though not yet deprecated, it probably will be). [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) is the new way.

Side note 2: By preventing the default, you're preventing the URL from changing (e.g., the new hash), which means if people bookmark it, they won't have the right hash.

Comment: The problem is that the links don't start with `#` as I said in my question. I said that the anchor is the whole link like `www.mywebsite.com/#myanchor`. I cannot add an href only with `#myanchor` since it is the nav menu and those link will not work from other pages.

Comment: @Tasos: I don't see that in the question. So you're saying that on the page `http://www.mywebsite.com/`, you have links like `http://www.mywebsite.com/#myanchor`? Why? It's just page bloat, and makes this process more difficult.

Comment: It is the main nav menu. A few of the links are anchors for the homepage. The others for single pages. If I add as href only the `#myanchor` and click on it from a single page, it will not redirect to the homepage to that div.

Comment: @Tasos: If you're linking to *a different page*, you can't do this scrollto effect on the "from" page at all; you'd have to do it on the *target* page.

Comment: I know it. The scroll effect is only when you click on the link and you ARE on the homepage. When you are on another single page, it will just redirect to the homepage to the specific div without any effect. That's why I have the full link.

Comment: It worked and I appreciate the comments. I will change it to on click instead of bind and try to improve it more based on what you said